# Как удалить дубли в CSS?

Tags: css

Есть огромный файл 300 кб в CSS. 
И в нем обнаруживаются перемешанные дубли стилей. 
Посоветуйте чем пройтись и почистить дубли.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320591/how-to-check-for-duplicate-css-rules

Comment: Главное, чтоб автоматика удалила верные дубли, а то потом будет голова болеть

Answer (score 4):

[Устанавливаете Node JS](https://nodejs.org/en/download/), если у вас он еще не установлен.

Далее вызываете командную строку и вводите команду

```
npm install css-purge -g
```

После успешной установки заходите в папку, где у вас размещен файл css, и там уже вызываете другую команду

```
css-purge -i style.css -o style_purged.css
```

где `style.css` - имя вашего файла, а `style_purged.css` - соответственно файл с удаленными дубликатами. Только осторожно, поскольку будут удалены и комментарии.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-purge

> [оригинальный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320591/how-to-check-for-duplicate-css-rules)

Comment: стоит добавить в ответ ссылку на источник перевода